# TFS xaml file and Jenkins - Trying to Build a Solution Ms build

Tags: xaml, msbuild, jenkins

We are using TFS 2010 and Xaml File to build the solution into zip package. My company does not have a .proj msbuild script( since we are using TFS 2010 they are building directly using the Xaml file in TFS and building from solution)

Now i am trying to do a Msbuild 4.0 package using jenkins and TFS as our repository.

Issue: since i dont have a .proj(build script) i cannot call it in jenkins.

how can i use the Tfs2010 Xaml in jenkins ?

please any direction will help .

Answer (score 0):

either migrate the custom parts of the xaml file into a script or google how to host a workflowfoundation (WF) xaml file. You might have to write a console application which starts the WF pipeline.